# With `.to_dict()`, pandas converts `NaN` to `nan` in python dictionary ; How to check if 'nan' exists in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a sample CSV file:

```
X,Y
A,
B,
C,D
```

After reading this file, pandas treats empty cell as `NaN` values:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
```

```
  X   Y
0 A NaN
1 B NaN
2 C   D
```

and after converting this to lists of python dictionaries, `NaN` becomes `nan`

```py
>> d = df.to_dict(orient='records')

[{'X': 'A', 'Y': nan}, {'X': 'B', 'Y': nan}, {'X': 'C', 'Y': 'D'}]
```

I'm trying to find where null exits using `math.isnan()`,  but it throws an exception

```py
for i,v in enumerate(d):
    if math.isnan(v['Y']):
        print(I)
```

```
0
1
TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

Exception can be handle using

```py
for i,v in enumerate(d):
    try:
        if math.isnan(v['Y']):
            print(i)
    except:
        pass
```

But is there a better way to find `nan` values??

Comment: This method seems fine. Indeed, `math.isnan('D')` is an error since `math.isnan` works on numbers, not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use [`pandas.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isna.html):

```
for i,v in enumerate(d):
    if pd.isna(v['Y']):
        print('I')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any function, you can compare the value to itself. NaNs have this interesting property to be different from themselves:

```
for i,v in enumerate(d):
    if v['Y']!=v['Y']:
        print(i)
```

output

```
0
1
```

Another possibility would be to generate this list from the DataFrame itself (note that you would get the real indices here, so 0, 1 if this is a range index otherwise the first and second values of the index):

```
s = df['Y'].isna()
na_indices = s[s].index.to_list()
```

output: `[0, 1]`

Comment: I mean it works... but it is rather unintuitive... and while I can't think of an example off the top of my head... other objects may also decide (no idea why they'd want to do that) they're not equal to themselves for some reason...

Comment: @JonClements yes that's always possible, but extremely unlikely in the described case (dictionary generated from a pandas DataFrame)